# Issue url pagination auto change on Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have written a function to create pagination in functions.php

The desired link for my pagination is:

```
http://localhost/board?page=2
```

But when clicked, it was changed to:

```
http://localhost/board/2/
```

Is there any way to keep the url from being changed? keep query variable on url `?page=2`
Thank everyone!

```
if (!function_exists('pagination_custom')):
    function pagination_custom($paged, $max_num_pages)
{
        echo '<nav class="pagination-custom">';
        echo '<ul class="pagination justify-content-center">';
        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => add_query_arg('page', '%#%'),
            'format' => '?page=%#%',
            'current' => $paged,
            'total' => $max_num_pages,
            'prev_text' => '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/images/icon-arrow-left-white.svg" . '" alt="">',
            'next_text' => '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/images/icon-arrow-right-white.svg" . '" alt="">',
        ));
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</nav>';
    }
endif;
```

Permalink Settings:
[image]

Comment: So by _“But when clicked, it was changed to”_, you mean the URL is first output in the correct format in your HTML, but then changes _afterwards_? Then you probably need to go and look into your URL rewriting setup.

Comment: @CBroe yes! I chose to replace the letter "page" with "page_num", temporary method!